# Not working after reupload main javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, nginx

I've changed one line in my main.js file using nano command.

Here is the line.

*Before:*

```
document.location = '?premium,promotion';
```

*After:*

```
document.location = '?premium,8';
```

And I just saved it. Now, I see that nothing of the other functions in my main.js is working. I changed the line on that one before and the same.

I'm using Nginx on debian. Maybe I should restart ajax or something?
When I **explore** in my chrome browser I see that error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: userid is not defined main.js:140
```

The 140 line of main.js is:

```
// user activity
$.post('ajax.php', { action: 'activity', user: userid });
setInterval(function() {
    $.post('ajax.php', { action: 'activity', user: userid });
}, 60*1000);
```

Here is main.js file:

http://pastebin.com/wgH7N4Da

And here is ajax.php:

http://pastebin.com/ewueSuQn

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I saw the js code, and as per the error says, you need to define a userid as variable or put inside a single quotes.

Comment: But i didn't changed anything else. For example ajax.php I didn't changed it.